# Why do actiones on concated array effect both arrays after changes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, concatenation

I run the process below to gather all product attributes and options from an object, in order to update a product.

For some strange reason, the main array categoryUrls get changed, and I can't seem to understand why.

After the following process, `categoryUrls[random key].attributes.options` gets new values added.

```
const {categoryUrls} = require('./helpers/categoryUrls.js')

getCategory = function (categoryUrls) {

    let att = []
    
    for (const key in categoryUrls) {
        if (categoryUrls[key].attributes) {// check if has attribute 
            att = att.concat(categoryUrls[key].attributes)
            
            for(var i=0; i<att.length; ++i) {// check if attribute ID already exist and remove duplicates
                for(var j=i+1; j<att.length; ++j) {
                    if(att[i].id === att[j].id){
                        for (let k = 0; k < att[j].options.length; k++) { // if attribute ID already exist unite options
                            let exist = att[i].options.find(option => option == att[j].options[k]) // check if option no already exist 
                            if (!exist) {
                                att[i].options.push(att[j].options[k])
                            }
                        }
                        att.splice(j--, 1);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return att
}


let data = getCategory(categoryUrls)
productData = productData.concat(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you are trying to save the new array into `att`, but let the original one unmutated, but you're applying the process right on categoryUrls. Is that correct? If so, remember that arrays are reference types, so, if you work them you change the actual array, they don't work as strings or integers.

Try to copy the array before working it and apply the process on its copy.

Try this:

```
const {categoryUrls} = require('./helpers/categoryUrls.js')

getCategory = function (categoryUrls) {

    let newArray = [...categoryUrls]

    let att = []
    
    for (const key in categoryUrls) {
        if (categoryUrls[key].attributes) {// check if has attribute 
            att = att.concat(newArray[key].attributes)
            
            for(var i=0; i<att.length; ++i) {// check if attribute ID already exist and remove duplicates
                for(var j=i+1; j<att.length; ++j) {
                    if(att[i].id === att[j].id){
                        for (let k = 0; k < att[j].options.length; k++) { // if attribute ID already exist unite options
                            let exist = att[i].options.find(option => option == att[j].options[k]) // check if option no already exist 
                            if (!exist) {
                                att[i].options.push(att[j].options[k])
                            }
                        }
                        att.splice(j--, 1);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return att
}


let data = getCategory(categoryUrls)
productData = productData.concat(data)
```

Comment: i think [... a..b..] is the same as concat method. I think also the issue is that the array contains objects. As you said, it's not like string and numbers. so this  [... a..b..] won't work as well.